# How to solve Leverage browser caching in wordpress pagespeed insight

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, caching

I am struggling with Leverage browser caching problem. I have applied all effort as I can do but no success. May be I am not working in right direction.

i am on godaddy server, I am unable to install w3 total cache plugin to resolve this type problem.

I am getting this:

```
http://s.gravatar.com/js/gprofiles.js (expiration not specified)
http://mydomain.netdna-cdn.com/…t-scrollbar-0.4.6.with-mousewheel.min.js (60 minutes)
http://mydomain.netdna-cdn.com/…gins/wp-google-maps/css/wpgmza_style.css (60 minutes)
http://mydomain.netdna-cdn.com/…ins/revslider/rs-plugin/css/settings.css (60 minutes)
http://mydomain.netdna-cdn.com/…/themes/inovado/framework/css/retina.css (60 minutes)
http://mydomain.netdna-cdn.com/…content/plugins/optin-panel/js/script.js (60 minutes)
http://mydomain.netdna-cdn.com/…hemes/inovado/framework/js/mobilemenu.js (60 minutes)
http://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js (2 hours)
```

I have applied some code in `.htaccess` file and try to solve this problem by some plugin, But no luck.

Please help to resolve this Leverage browser caching in wordpress.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those files are located within your servers you can use: Leverage Browser Caching Ninjas Plugin! It's very effective! If they are not located within the server then there is nothing you can do about it. (they are an external sources that is linked to your site) .htacess rules won't fix those issues! Good Luck!

John

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use wpsupercache. Some provider do block caching plugins. I suggest you take a look at their blog or statemens. Htaccess code you can use (i do it too:)

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
```